# Meaning of SchedulingClass in SYSTEM_CPU_SET_INFORMATION

Tags: winapi, cpu

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-system_cpu_set_information

MSDN says nothing about it, but I'm wondering what does SchedulingClass mean?

I'm looking at AMD Threadripper PRO 5975WX (32 core / 64 logical processors) that has the same cores (from Windows point of view) with EfficiencyClass=0 except SchedulingClass. The SchedulingClass is different for the first 32 logical cores, but the last 32 cores have SchedulingClass=0. What's the difference? Does this somehow affect the performance of cores?

I also compared the frequencies and PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION of each core and they are all the same.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ns-winnt-jobobject_basic_limit_information

Answer (score 7):

(Note: a bit heavy on assembly and kernel stuff).

Since the structure is a bit hard to parse (even visually), so the offset of the `SchedulingClass` is 20 (0x14):

```c
    size_t offScheduling = offsetof(SYSTEM_CPU_SET_INFORMATION, CpuSet.SchedulingClass);
    printf("off: %llu", offScheduling);  // prints 20
```

The structure itself is used by [`GetSystemCpuSetInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/getsystemcpusetinformation) (exported by `kernel32.dll`).

In fact it is located in `kernelbase.dll` through export forwarding. The function is a wrapper around `nt!NtQuerySystemInformationEx` (thus a kernel function) with case 0xAF:

```
00007FFC8C22C5D0 <kernelbase.GetSystemCpuSetInformation>
; ...
00007FFC8C22C60E  mov ecx,AF
00007FFC8C22C613  call qword ptr ds:[<&NtQuerySystemInformationEx>]
```

For case 0xAF, `nt!NtQuerySystemInformationEx` calls `nt!ExpQuerySystemInformation` (with the same case number), and we land here:

```
PAGE:000000014069215C loc_14069215C:
PAGE:000000014069215C    mov     rcx, [rsp+338h+Handle] ; jumptable 000000014068F773 case 175
PAGE:0000000140692164    test    rcx, rcx
PAGE:0000000140692167    jz      short loc_1406921A9
PAGE:0000000140692169    mov     r8, cs:PsProcessType ; ObjectType
PAGE:0000000140692170    mov     [rsp+338h+var_238], r14
PAGE:0000000140692178    mov     [rsp+338h+HandleInformation], r14 ; HandleInformation
PAGE:000000014069217D    lea     rax, [rsp+338h+var_238]
PAGE:0000000140692185    mov     [rsp+338h+Object], rax ; Object
PAGE:000000014069218A    movzx   r9d, r12b       ; AccessMode
PAGE:000000014069218E    mov     edx, 1000h      ; DesiredAccess
PAGE:0000000140692193    call    ObReferenceObjectByHandle
PAGE:0000000140692198    mov     r14, [rsp+338h+var_238]
PAGE:00000001406921A0    test    eax, eax
PAGE:00000001406921A2    jns     short loc_1406921B1
PAGE:00000001406921A4    jmp     loc_1406925ED
PAGE:00000001406921A9 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PAGE:00000001406921A9
PAGE:00000001406921A9 loc_1406921A9:                          ; CODE XREF: ExpQuerySystemInformation+2D87↑j
PAGE:00000001406921A9    mov     r14, [rsp+338h+Process]
PAGE:00000001406921B1
PAGE:00000001406921B1 loc_1406921B1:                          ; CODE XREF: ExpQuerySystemInformation+2DC2↑j
PAGE:00000001406921B1    mov     r9, r14
PAGE:00000001406921B4    lea     r8, [rsp+338h+Size]
PAGE:00000001406921B9    mov     edx, edi
PAGE:00000001406921BB    mov     rcx, rbx        ; void *
PAGE:00000001406921BE    call    KeQueryCpuSetInformation
```

What happens above: if you passed a process handle to `GetSystemCpuSetInformation`, the handle is first dereferenced (that is, handle -> `_EPROCESS`) and then `nt!KeQueryCpuSetInformation` is called.

In `nt!KeQueryCpuSetInformation` we have this code:

```
PAGE:00000001407B4D02    call    KiGetCpuSetData
PAGE:00000001407B4D07    mov     r13, rax
; ...
PAGE:00000001407B4D56    mov     al, [r13+6]
PAGE:00000001407B4D5A    mov     [r11+14h], al  ; set SchedulingClass!
```

So, `nt!KiGetCpuSetData` returns a structure; from this structure the value at offset +6 is used to set the `SchedulingClass` field.

(Note that `r11` is the output structure).

Now let's see in `nt!KeQueryCpuSetInformation`:

```
.text:0000000140360D94 KiGetCpuSetData proc near
.text:0000000140360D94
.text:0000000140360D94                 shl     ecx, 6
.text:0000000140360D97                 lea     eax, [rdx+rcx]
.text:0000000140360D9A                 shl     rax, 4
.text:0000000140360D9E                 add     rax, cs:KiCpuSetData
.text:0000000140360DA5                 retn
.text:0000000140360DA5 KiGetCpuSetData endp
```

So everything comes from a global variable named `nt!KiCpuSetData`. Looking at the reference to this structure we just have a few hits.

One is interesting at `nt!KiConfigureCpuSetSchedulingInformation`:

```
.text:00000001403B284C KiConfigureCpuSetSchedulingInformation proc near
; ...
.text:00000001403B2865                 mov     rsi, rcx
...
.text:00000001403B28C3                 add     r8, cs:KiCpuSetData
; ...
.text:00000001403B293B                 mov     al, [rsi+81B9h]
.text:00000001403B2941                 mov     [r8+6], al  ; set offset +6.
```

So, `RSI` is a structure, the code uses offset 0x81B9 to set the offset +6 in the current structure in `KiCpuSetData`.

`rsi` actually points to the `_KPRCB` (Kernel Processor Control Block) structure which is a structure that (basically) represents a CPU for the kernel (alongside its host structure, the `_KPCR`; Kernel Processor Control Region).

```
PAGE:00000001408B7295                 lea     rax, KiProcessorBlock  ; global system KPRCB
PAGE:00000001408B729C                 mov     ecx, edi
PAGE:00000001408B729E                 mov     rcx, [rax+rcx*8]  ; pick the one for the current processor.
PAGE:00000001408B72A2                 call    KiConfigureCpuSetSchedulingInformation
```

Let's see offset 0x81B9:

```c
typedef struct _KPRCB                                                     // 351 elements, 0xAF00 bytes (sizeof)
{
    // ...

    /*0x7FF8*/     VOID*        MmInternal;
    /*0x8000*/     struct _PROCESSOR_POWER_STATE PowerState;                             // 46 elements, 0x200 bytes (sizeof)
    /*0x8200*/     VOID*        HyperPte;

    // ...
}KPRCB, *PKPRCB;
```

We have a structure at 0x8000, so it's inside this structure at offset 0x1B9 (0x8000 + 0x1B9 = 0x81B9):

```c
typedef struct _PROCESSOR_POWER_STATE                         // 46 elements, 0x200 bytes (sizeof)
{

// ...

/*0x1B8*/     UINT8        ArchitecturalEfficiencyClass;
/*0x1B9*/     UINT8        PerformanceSchedulingClass;
/*0x1BA*/     UINT8        EfficiencySchedulingClass;

// ...
}PROCESSOR_POWER_STATE, *PPROCESSOR_POWER_STATE;
```

So the name of the field is `PerformanceSchedulingClass`. I didn't push further my investigations (where this field is actually set up)
but there's a nice explanation in [this slide deck from AMD](https://gpuopen.com/gdc-presentations/2022/GDC_AMD_Ryzen_Processor_Software_Optimization.pdf), page 19:

> Some AMD products have cores which are faster than other cores.
> The system BIOS describes the CPPC Highest Performance ranking for each logical processor.
> The Windows Kernel creates a PerformanceSchedulingClass ranking based on this information and uses it during scheduling.
> Logical processor 0 and CCD0 may not be the fastest.

As far as I understand the above and from the code we've seen in the kernel, this `SchedulingClass` is used by the kernel to sort processors in groups based on how much they perform from a ground base? (I'm not a CPU specialist).

Comment: This is what I've looking for, thank you! I was selecting the most performant cores by sorting them by EfficiencyClass, it looks like I need to sort by SchedulingClass too.